# To knit an external pagedown rmd file to a pdf

Tags: pagedown

Is it possible in a pagedown rmd file to call and knit an external pagedown rmd file?

I tried `rmarkdown::render()` in an r code chunk.  It did not work.

Comment: it is not currently possible to call and knit an external pagedown rmd file in a pagedown rmd file. However, you could use rmarkdown::render() in an R code chunk to call and render the external pagedown file and then include the output in your pagedown file.

Comment: Do you mean I could render the output to pdf in my pagedown file?